# Launching an Instance Store backed Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just wanted to know, how can I launch an Instance Store Backed Instance, on the EC2 launch page I see all EBS backed AMIs. Don't see any Instance store backed AMI. Do I have to create an Instance Store Backed AMI first to launch an Instance Store backed instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an **instance store-backed AMI**.

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance in the management console:

- Select **Community AMIs**
- For **Root device type**, select *Instance store*
- Select a desired AMI

By the way, there is **very little benefit** these days in booting off instance store, compared to the benefits that EBS provides (start/stop, snapshots, resizing, etc).

Comment: Thanks got it. I was looking for those AMI's on Quick Start tab , but found it under Community AMI's. Yes launching Instance Store backed AMI's not that as useful as EBS backed, just wanted to do it for curiosity.